# How to pass a dataframe into a function and put the output back into the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and in a certain column there are some missing values. I want to replace them by comparing values from a different column. I have to do this multiple times in the total code with different column names. There fore I want to build a function who does this:

```
df
#   A     B      C
#   1   "USA"   1999
#   2     NA    1999
#   3   "GER"   1999
#   3   "GER"   1999
```

no I want to replace all values in column B which equal in column A to 2 with "ABC". using levels here because one col consists of factors(?)

```
levels(df$B) <- c(levels(df$B), "ABC") 
df$B[df$A==2]  <- "ABC"
```

so this works fine. output is exactly what I want it to be:

```
df
#   A     B      C
#   1   "USA"   1999
#   2   "ABC"   1999
#   3   "GER"   1999
#   3   "GER"   1999
```

but I want to put this in a function, because in my project are different datasets with different names and column names as well as different numbers to convert into other strings then "ABC". So how to pass in the names of the dataset and the columns? this is my try:

```
fun1 <- <- function(dataset,col1,col2) {
    levels(dataset$col1) <- c(levels(dataset$col1), "ABC")
    dataset$col1[dataset$col2==2]  <- "ABC"
    return(dataset)
}
```

But I always get this error message:

```
 Error in levels(dataset$col1) <- c(levels(dataset$col1), "ABC") : 
      attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `&` as with `$`, it looks for a column named 'col1' or 'col2' instead of the value associated with the argument

```
fun1 <-  function(dataset,col1,col2) {
  levels(dataset[[col1]]) <- c(levels(dataset[[col1]]), "ABC")
  dataset[[col1]][dataset[[col2]]==2]  <- "ABC"
  return(dataset)
  }

fun1(df, "B", "A")
#  A   B    C
#1 1 USA 1999
#2 2 ABC 1999
#3 3 GER 1999
#4 3 GER 1999
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), B = structure(c(2L, NA, 
 1L, 1L), .Label = c("GER", "USA"), class = "factor"), C = c(1999L, 
 1999L, 1999L, 1999L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this helped! Thank you! You have to pass the column arguments in as strings/characters. Please upvote this answer becaus I have not enough reputation here to do so! Thank you!

Comment: @1Z3173C0D3. If you want to parse it as unquoted, then may need `deparse` substitute